# Apache Error directive ignoring ErrorDocument directive

Tags: apache, error-handling

I wrote on my *.htaccess* an *if* to check if the *mod_rewrite* is installed and throw error **500** if not.

```
ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    Error "mod_rewrite not installed"
</IfModule>
```

If i get an **500** error by it will show the **500**.html. But if it gets that same error from the *Error* directive, it will show the default error page instead. Why ? How do i fix it ?

Comment: Whoever downvoted my question and answer, please comment why. I would be gratefull to receive a better answer or explanation. Seriously. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after thinking a lot about it and reading a bit, i believe that the `Error` function simply makes the `.htaccess` parsing to be **cancelled** - *and the error to be logged* - and then throw an **500 error** from the *apache config* that has been parsed *before* this one (for example, an `.htaccess` from another folder *over* this one or the `httpd.conf` from apache)